# Properties grid on Android - readonly and/or editable

Tags: android

I need to create a properties grid in my application to allow the user to read (initially) and eventually edit the properties of an object that I display using a custom list adapter.

I did some research and found that Android has the preferences activity, which sounds good as far as the UI portion, but I don't want to actually save "preferences", I need an edit screen.

Is there a way to have a dialog created which will use reflection (sorry, .net term) to create the dialog allowing the user to edit each property of an object, or do I need to create this manually?  Either is ok, I just need to know.  Thanks!